# Rails: Log rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, rake-task

I am trying to log the output of a rake task to a new logger.  Ideally the solution would work in development and production.

Here is my task:

```
task :clients, [:field] => [:setup_logger] do |t, args|
    clients = Client.all
    problems = []

    group = clients.group_by { |client| client[args[:field]] }
    unique_ids = group.keys

    unique_ids.each do |unique_id|
        problems << [unique_id, group[unique_id].length] if group[unique_id].length != 1
    end

    if !problems.blank?
        logger = Logger.new("db_issues.log")
        logger.error "look at me"
        logger.close
    end

    p problems
end
```

When I run this, even though `problems` is not blank, no new log file is created.  **How am I supposed to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `logger.close`, look after boot you server for a message like this:

> log writing failed. closed stream

try removing `logger.close` from your code and restarting your server.

Comment: I still don't see any file `db_issues.log` in my log folder

Comment: It's in my root folder -_- .  Thanks!

Comment: To create the log file under the log folder you can follow as below:

    logfile = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'log', 'db_issues.log'),  'a')
    logger = Logger.new(logfile)
    logger.error "look at me"